# How to listen the keypress in the soft keyboard?

Tags: android, keyboard, listener, keylistener

I need a listener to identify the keypress in the soft keyboard/on screen keyboard.

I tried with addtextchangelistener textwatcher but this one give the good result but it shows the change also when some text is pasted into it.

I need to identify only the key press by the user.

Is there any possible way to detect the key press.

Answer (score 3):

see this [keyevent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) and use following code to identify which key is pressed by Users.

```
  @Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) 
    {
         // Do Code here
    }
else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_0) 
   {

   }
else if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1) 
   {

   }
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); }
```

Comment: only works if no text entered to the EditText and I am pressing the backslash button

Comment: This may not work, because software keyboards don't have to send KeyEvents (some keyboards send none, Gboard sends only ASCII keys).

Answer (score 3):

> When handling keyboard events with the KeyEvent class and related
>   APIs, you should expect that such keyboard events come only from a
>   hardware keyboard. **You should never rely on receiving key events for
>   any key on a soft input method (an on-screen keyboard)**.

see: [Handling Keyboard Actions](https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands.html)

Comment: the guy is asking about the soft keyboard, not the hardware keyboard

Comment: You should never rely on receiving key events for any key on a soft input method (an on-screen keyboard)

Answer (score 1):

See this if can help you.

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 1) {          
            finish();
            return true;    
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // Do Code here
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: This is to identify the back keypress.

Comment: you can identify any key available on keyboard.

Comment: I have already tried onKeyDown listens only for the soft keys and not in the keyboard