# How to listener the soft keyboard key event

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

how to know when I press the delete key from the soft keyboard in android, an event the content of the edittext is empty. I know when the content is not empty, can use TextChangeListener. Only the empty content how to listen the pressed key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to listen the keypress in the soft keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616567/how-to-listen-the-keypress-in-the-soft-keyboard)

Comment: Use setOnKeyListener for this

Comment: setListener is not worked in same android system. Finally I got a smart idea, which can use a space replace by ImageSpan，and set picture size is 0*0. So there always will not be empty.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

setListener is not worked in same android system. Finally I got a smart idea, which can use a space replace by ImageSpan，and set picture size is 0*0. So there always will not be empty.

Answer (score -1):

KeyEvent provides keyboard events

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
            // Do Code here
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```