# Triggering some functionality when the user presses the backspace/erase via the soft keyboard

Tags: android, user-controls, listener, android-softkeyboard, backspace

i have a **function that should be performed** only **when the user presses the backspace/erase button** on the soft keyboard,

**i don't know how**

Any suggestions would be helpful!

[image]

Comment: Does this help - [edittext_backspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4886858/android-edittext-deletebackspace-key-event)

Comment: You're introducing me to the textWatcher, let me first learn how it works and see if i can achieve with textWatcher

Comment: i tried with OnKeylistener() it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you go over this: https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands. And this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10616567/how-to-listen-the-keypress-in-the-soft-keyboard ?

Comment: if it still doesn't work with @gioravered suggestions , please add your code of what you have tried

Comment: Okay i will, mate